# Integrate $\int_{\partial G}(x,y,z) \times N dS$ for $G \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ with a smooth, regular boundary.

Tags: calculus, integration, manifolds, stokes-theorem

Integrate $\int_{\partial G}(x,y,z) \times N  dS$ for $G \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ with a smooth, regular boundary.

$N$ the outward-pointing normal to $\partial G$, and the integral is evaluated per element of the vector.

I'm sure I should use the divergence theorem somewhere here, but I'm not exactly sure how to  apply it. For example, I looked at the first entry in the cross product vector and got $yn_z - zn_y$ where $N = (n_x,n_y,n_z)$, but I'm not sure how to continue from here. I feel like I'm missing something... Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is $(x,y,z)$? Is that field $\mathbf{F}=x\mathbf{i}+y\mathbf{j}+z\mathbf{k}$? Are you sure that there is cross product in the formulation? The common task is to calculate $\int_{\partial G}(\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{N})dS$ with the *dot* product.  What is $G$? Is that three-dimensional region? If so, you should use the divergence theorem, not the Stokes' theorem.

Comment: Yes, that is the field. The question talks about the cross product. Yes, of course I mistakenly said Stoke's when I meant divergence. Thanks.

Comment: So what is exactly the integrand? $\mathbf{F}\times\mathbf{N}$ is a vector. Is $dS$ scalar? Is it $\int_{\partial G}(\mathbf{F}\times\mathbf{N})dS$? If so, the result is supposed to be a vector, right? Is the region $G$ specified?

Comment: No, $G$ isn't specified. The question asks to integrate each entry of the vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be an answer (we know, that the answer is a vector).

Let us calculate $A_x$. You have written correctly, that:

$$
A_x=\int_{\partial G}(yn_z-zn_y)dS=\int_{\partial G}(\mathbf{f}\cdot \mathbf{N})dS.
$$
Here $\mathbf{f}=(0,-z,y)$. Now we may use the divergence theorem for the latter integral. $\mathrm{div}\mathbf{f}=0$, so the integral is $0$, and so $A_x=0$.

We may perform the same trick for $A_y$ and $A_z$. We will obtain $A_x=A_y=A_z=0$. So the answer is $\mathbf{A}=0$.

If we assume that the task *may be solved*, but the region $G$ *is not specified*, not that many opportunities remain. $\mathbf{A}=0$ is one of them.

Comment: Thanks for this, I knew there was a trick I was missing. Why does it depend on $G$? Seems to me like as long as the divergence theorem holds (which it does), the integral has to be $0$.

Comment: @JohnB It was an *heuristic* argument I had in mind *before* solving. What are we supposed to obtain? Some "ugly" $\mathbf{A}$ like $(1.38, 17, 27/7)$? But these "ugly" numbers will likely depend on $G$. If $G$ is not specified, it will be likely impossible even to write down an answer. If we still think, that the task is solvable (we expect that from the textbook task), the answer may only be "good": $0$, or some function of the volume of $G$ (or area of $\partial G$), or something connected with the total solid angle etc. The answer turned out to be the simplest one: $0$.

Comment: @JohnB In fact, the method described above may be used for an arbitrary "ugly" $\mathbf{F}$. We can rewrite $\int_{\partial G}(\mathbf{F}\times\mathbf{N})dS$ in terms of more common $\int_{\partial G}(\mathbf{f}\cdot\mathbf{N})dS$, $\int_{\partial G}(\mathbf{g}\cdot\mathbf{N})dS$ etc. But we will have to specify $G$ to get the final result.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!